# RJDBC connection to RedShift produces a .jfindClass class not found error on Windows

Tags: r, windows, amazon-redshift

Good morning, I'm trying to connect amazon redshift  but when I run this command

```
driver <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver", "RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar", identifier.quote="`")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
```

I have  R version 3.2.2 on Windows 7

```
J("java.lang.System")$getProperty("java.version")
[1] "1.7.0_67"

java -version
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using 1.1.7.1007 driver in scala without any problem

did you do

```
install.packages("RJDBC",dep=TRUE)
```

And full path to the jar?

Comment: I try to reinstall the package, with the command that you mention and using the full path but is not working, I get the same error

Comment: Yeah, one reason to throw class not found is that it cannot find the whole jar. I tried what you did on my machine without any problem. You mind wanna try putting jar into directory that you get with getwd() command.